# Can one crashing application cause another application to crash on a Windows Server 2016 machine?

Tags: windows, crash, .net-framework, windows-server-2016

On a Windows Server 2016 computer, there are some series of crashes, as described in Event log:

First crash: Notepad.exe

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: AppHangB1
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: notepad.exe
P2: 10.0.14393.4169
P3: 5ff78d1b
P4: 7b5e
P5: 134217728
P6: 
P7: 
P8: 
P9: 
P10:
```

Second crash : Notepad.exe

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: AppHangB1
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: notepad.exe
P2: 10.0.14393.4169
P3: 5ff78d1b
P4: 997c
P5: 134217728
P6: 
P7: 
P8: 
P9: 
P10:
```

Next crash : My_application

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: CLR20r3
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: My_Application.exe
P2: 1.0.0.0
P3: 5847d8dc
P4: mscorlib
P5: 4.7.3890.0
P6: 615bbf2d
P7: 42b9
P8: a4
P9: System.IO.FileLoadException
P10:
```

In general: my application shows a very large file (a logfile) and when notepad.exe tries to open that logfile, notepad.exe crashes.

My manager claims that my application does not cause Notepad.exe to open that file, but I have heavy doubts about that: why would an application crash, immediately after the crash of Notepad.exe, if that application is not related to Notepad.exe?
So I see different possible root causes here:

- Either Windows Server 2016 allows different applications to "intervene" in some way, which might cause crash snowball-effects. Is this possible? Or:
- Notepad.exe is linked to my application. In that case, does is there some way to prove that from the event logs?

**Edit after first comment**
I've added the `.Net` tag as My_Application is indeed a .Net application and that might be relevant for this question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Or third option, your app uses a framework that notepad uses also, such as .net and something under water breaks?

Comment: @LPChip: so you are saying that Notepad is a .Net application, running on the .Net virtual machine, and when it has a problem it might crash the entire .Net virtual machine, causing all .Net applications to crash too? This looks like an enormous quality hole, don't you think?

Comment: @LPChip: is there a way to detect whether either an application or the entire .Net virtual machine is crashing?

Comment: No, I was saying that there may be an underlying cause. notepad is a simple program that has a text edit control, a menu and that's it, but if it shares something that your program uses too and that dll is corrupted, could be the problem here. It is possible notepad has been rewritten to use .net nowadays, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: "My manager claims that my application does not cause Notepad.exe to open that file" I would have thought Process Monitor would prove this to be true or not.

Comment: @HelpingHand: and how can Process Monitor solve this?

Comment: Well it would answer the question "My manager claims that my application does not cause Notepad.exe to open that file". Process Monitor would answer this specific question. It might help understand the crash, but that's not what I was answering.  If you want to share a PML and a process dump of both processes I'd take a look.  I'd suggest run `procdump -ma -i C:\dumps\` from an admin prompt.  You can get Procdump from Sysinternals.  As the processes crash, you will get a complete dump for each written to C:\dumps\ A PML file covering the 2 dumps would be interesting.